# Website load perfectly from localhost but after 3 or 4 hours is not load from remote computer until restart iis

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, asp.net

I have a web application on IIS 7.5 and windows server 2008 r2.
It's load perfectly from localhost but after 3 or 4 hours is not load from remote computer until restart iis or recycle pool.

Users of this site are about 900 people.
Some setting of my pool:
.Net frame work version: v2.0
Manage pipe line mode: Integrated
Enable 32-Bit applications: true

Identity: Administrator
Idle time-out: 120

Load user profile: false

Rapid fail protection enabled: false
Disable recycling for configuration changes: true

---

I saw many cases in error log in C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Some of them are very frequent:

1. Connection_Dropped system
2. Timer_ConnectionIdle
3. Timer_MinBytesPerSecond

How to compile these error?
What that's mean?

I get this error frequent in event viewer:
A process serving application pool 'system' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '8208'. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: What does resource usage of the worker process look like?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2 is my database and i use Excel, XML, CSV for import data from application

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough info to take a guess yet. Here are some suggestions on things to do to troubleshooting further:

1. Check Event Viewer for clues
2. Check the IIS logs for the actual http status code
3. Sometimes errors early in the pipeline can be found here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
4. Failed Request tracing will give good clues.
5. Test with a simple test.aspx page before and during when it fails to see how that compares to the rest of the site. Make sure that the test page doesn't use a database connection.

I've seen an issue like you mention at least a couple times and it had something to do with the open connections to the database just for remote anonymous users, so the test.aspx page will confirm whether the issue is at the app pool level in IIS or if it's something to do with the database.